# SQL Data Hierarchy Mapping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy, recursive-query

[image: Problem]

The first data table shows the hierarchy structure and Im trying to show how each level relates to all the children underneath. The output I'm looking for is the second table.

Any pointers of how to do this in T-SQL please?

Answer (score 0):

A [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) is what you use to get this output:

```
WITH reccte AS 
(
    /*Recursive Seed (first result set upon which we iterate)*/
    SELECT CUSTOMERNO, CUSTOMER_PARENT, HIERARCHY
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE CUSTOMERNO NOT IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_PARENT FROM yourtable)

    UNION ALL

    /*Recursive Member - The part that refers to itself that iterates until the join fails*/
    SELECT 
         reccte.CUSTOMERNO, yourtable.CUSTOMER_PARENT, yourtable.HIERARCHY
    FROM reccte
        INNER JOIN yourtable 
             ON reccte.CUSTOMER_PARENT = yourtable.CUSTOMERNO
)
/*select from the CTE output*/
SELECT * FROM reccte
UNION ALL
/*Union in those level 0 records (records that aren't a parent themselves*/
SELECT CUSTOMERNO, CUSTOMERNO, 0 FROM yourtable WHERE CUSTOMERNO NOT IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_PARENT FROM yourtable)
```